# how to call phtml file in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml

I want to call `show.phtml` file which will print database records from `entry.phtml` file.Here is the code of my files having-

**show.phtml**

```
<?php
 $model=Mage::getModel('entry/entry')->getCollection()->getData();
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($model);
 exit();

 ?>
```

**entry.phtml**

```
<h1>HELLO</h1>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl().'entry/index/save' ?>">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
    <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter Mobile">
    <input type="submit" value="Enter">

</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call your phtml file in another phtml file as below

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('module-folder-name/show.phtml')->toHtml() ?>
```

But if you want to show your phtml file from controller as you commented below my answer, you can call it as below.

Create a phtml file

> app/design/frontend/your/theme/template/module/show.phtml

```
<?php
 $model=Mage::getModel('entry/entry')->getCollection()->getData();
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($model);
 exit();

 ?>
```

Create an xml file

> app/design/frontend/your/theme/layout/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">   
  <module_index_index>   
    <reference name="root">   
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
    </reference>   
    <reference name="content">   
      <block type="module/index" name="module_index" template="module/show.phtml"/>   
    </reference>   
  </module_index_index>   
</layout>
```

Create a controller file

> app/code/local/Vendor/Module/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Vendor_Module_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function IndexAction() {

    $this->loadLayout();   
    $this->renderLayout(); 

    }
}
```

Comment: it works ,but open show.phtml file on same page. how to open show.phtml file in new tab ?

Comment: so what do you want exactly ?

Comment: to create a new function (showAction)  in indexController and open show.phtml file, using controller function .

Comment: See my updated code. I have used IndexAction. You can use it as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Place the bellow code where you want to call your file:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('path/to/show.phtml')->toHtml() ?>
```

Comment: Actually he needs to show his phtml file by using controller action.

Answer (score 0):

To call .phtml file through controller:

try this code--

```
public function showAction()
    {


    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template');

    // Assign your template to it
    // This path is relative to your current theme (eg: rwd/default/template/...)
    $block->setTemplate('entry/show.phtml');

    // Render the template to the browser
    echo $block->toHtml();
  }
```

}

in your main template(.phtml file) write this code:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->geturl("entry/index/show"); ?>">Show</a>
```